# Is there a way to recieve an object or a list in the same param of a REST call?

Tags: java, json, spring, list, spring-restcontroller

In java, you can add 3 dots in a function to say this can receive one, or more objects and I'm trying to implement this on a rest call

```
@PutMapping(value = FIELD_SAVE_URI)
    @Secured(CdsPermissionDefinition.CDS_MODIFY)
    public ResponseEntity<DefaultFieldDto> saveField(@RequestBody @NotNull DefaultFieldDto... fields){
        //TODO impl
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new DefaultFieldDto());
    }
```

Now, if I don't send list [] the server is giving me an error, but I want the option to receive an object {} or a list [] in the same param

```
void test(){
    a();
    a(new DefaultFieldDto());
    a(new DefaultFieldDto(), new DefaultFieldDto(), new DefaultFieldDto());
}


private void a(DefaultFieldDto... fields){
    //Do something
}
```

This is basically what I want to implement from a REST service perspective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is basically a bad design you are going for. As per REST standards PUT should accept only a JSON not a List.

But If you insist on List, you should support only List in the Request body. And for case of sending a object {}, send it as Array of one object [{}].

Comment: Well, this is more for fun and to try new things or "weird" stuff, my idea was to use the 3 dots to either receive an object or a list

and I want to receive the list because its possible the UI sends me a list of objects to update or save at the same time.